# tagging a new model - preloaded array produces an error - Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel, tags, laravel-5.1

I use this package as an egine for my tagging functionality:
https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-tagging

Now, when creating new model, in my controller I declare a variable with all available tags:

```
        $tags = array('' => 'Enter your tags...') + Tag::orderBy('name', 'asc')->lists('name', 'name')->all();
```

Then, in my create view I define this field:

```
    {!! Form::select('Tags[]', $tags, Input::old('Tags') ,['multiple' => 'multiple', 'data-tags' => 'true', 'data-token-separators' => "[',', ' ']", 'data-placeholder' => "{$tags['']}", 'class' => '']) !!}
```

#### Problem

when I write a first tag, say `politics`, two tags appear in the window: the `politics` and the empty tag defined in the controller `'' => 'Enter your tags...'`
I need to remove the tag manually each time I use the form.

When I remove the `array('' => 'Enter your tags...') +` part of my variable, 
I get error

```
`Undefined index: (View: resources/views/events/create.blade.php)`
```

### My question

how to make the select box work properly. 
Thx.